# How to split data according tо the maximum value

Tags: r, split

to analyze my bell shape data, i want to split the set Before and After the peak. I want to choose the values on those days which are before the max value (including the one at the peak). So in my example it has to be on days 1,2 and 3

Example:

```
check<-data.frame(day = c(1:5), A = c(0.2,0.8,1.6,1.0,0.4), 
                      B = c(0.3,0.7,1.3,0.7,0.3))

library(reshape2)

check_m<-melt(check, id=c("day"))

colnames(check_m)<-c("day","group","value")
```

Here is solution offered by a colleague:

```
befmax<-NULL

lll<-unique(check_m$group)

for (i in 1:length(lll)){

xxx<-subset(check_m, check_m$group==lll[i])

maxi<-subset(xxx, value==max(xxx$value))

xxx$bef<-(xxx$day<=maxi$day)

befmax<-rbind(befmax,xxx)
}
```

But it doesn't work with presented NA in real dataset. Adding `na.rm=T` doesn't help.
it returns an error note:

```
> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "bef", value = logical(0)) :   
> replacement has 0 rows, data has 5
```

Is there a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Where did you add `na.rm = T`? It should go inside `max()`. Can you show your desired output for the sample input?

Comment: Also, if you have a solution that works with no missing value, but you still have a problem when there are missing values, you should probably include missing values in your example.

Comment: `check_m %>% mutate(i = row_number() <=which.max(value)) %>% split(.$i) %>% map(select, -i)` Requires `library(dplyr)`

Comment: Do you want this for both group A and group B? And what do you want to do with the resulting values?

Comment: Sorry, i'll try again
i want to find a way how to choose values based on their relative position to the maximim value (peak one). Desired output of my example  
would be df which contains all variables, like this.
However, script, i added doesn't work if tab contains missing values
"day";"group";"value"
1;"A";0.2
2;"A";0.4
3;"A";1.6
1;"B";0.3
2;"B";0.7
3;"B";1.3

Comment: to Gregor.  just realized after careful reading that the answer was in your reply. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we can do this with `base R`

```
i1 <- with(check_m, ave(value, group, FUN = function(x) {
              x1 <- c(-Inf, diff(x))
            c(0, cumsum(x1==max(x1))[-length(x)])}))
split(check_m, list(check_m$group, i1), drop = FALSE)
```